# Grunt serve in Windows, how to?

Tags: windows, node.js, gruntjs

I have to switched on the second computer which is running on Windows XP.

I clonned my project from repository, which have structure containtng bower.jcon, Gruntfile.js and other following files and is running without problems on second computer with MacOS X.

After that I launched NodeJS command promtp, moved into the directory where application was clonned and i launched commmand.

```
C:\workspace\myproject>grunt serve
```

**And I got following error message:**

```
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'load-grunt-tasks'
Warning: Task "serve" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

Whhat I'm doing wrong and how can i solve this issue please?

Many thanks for any help.

**EDIT:**

I solved it using the following commands:

```
npm update npm -g
npm install
bower install
grunt serve
```

Comment: Looks like you haven't installed `load-grunt-tasks` module. FYI this has absolutely nothing to do with AngularJS...

Comment: Did you run `npm install`? Did you mean `grunt server`?

Comment: Add your edit as answer and accept it later